# Ionic 2 App currently used or not

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I am using cordova local notifications.

How to check my app is currently used or not.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: can you share more info about your use case?

Comment: Thanks For ur reply.I refered this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/local-notifications/ .I received notifications when app is used.But I need receive notifications only app is not used.similar to FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
          if(d.wasTapped){  
          })

Comment: Can u help me.or any other way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.on('click')` and execute a function that sends you that your app is beeing used. Something like:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from 'ionic-native';

LocalNotifications.on('click', (notification, state) => {
  // DO YOUR STUFF
});
```

You register this in the constructor or deviceReady of your `app.component.ts` so every time a user clicks on a notification it executes what's inside this block of code.

You could send to your phone a push, save something on a database, or anything you want. The `state` returns if the app was on background or foreground, with this you can manage even more doing a `if/else`.

If you need more events, look at this [wiki](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/09.-Events).

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks for ur relpy.Ya i also it's used.i opened my app and currently used.example i post new complaints or chat with friend.My app also received localnotifications.I need currently using for app does not receive notifications.How can i do this..

Comment: I need app is currently used does not receive notifications.and automatically redirect to another page.

Comment: i cannot understand how to use if else Localnotifications.on('click',..).

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you need, please update your question with more information so we can help you.

Comment: Actually I consoled the state value is everytime.it's  value is backround.then How can i check app opened or not